# Getting undefined error

Tags: javascript

```
<title>Ads</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/CSP.js">
</script>
</head>

<body>
   <div id="imagesDiv">
   <img src="images/cvb1.gif" alt="Image Ads"  id="oneImage"/>
   </div>

</body>
</html>

/---- code javascript--/

var theImage = document.getElementById("oneImage"); 
   changeAds();
   var intNumber = 0;
   var arrayOfImages = ["images/cvb1,gif","images/cvb2,gif","images/cvb3,gif"];
   // starting function ads 
   function changeAds(intNumber){
       theImage.setAttribute("src",arrayOfImages[intNumber]);
       intNumber ++;
       if (intNumber==arrayOfImages.length){
           intNumber=0;
       }
}
   setInterval(changeAds(),2000);
```

What did I do wrong?, I even tried to use `window.onload = function() {changeAds(intNumber)};` but  this even didn't work.
I am getting error

> "theImage.setAttribute("src",arrayOfImages[intNumber]); " is    undefined.

Comment: Use the window.onload, but remove the intNumber from (intNumber) in the call

Comment: Call the `changeAds()` function after declaring intNumber,arryOfImages

Comment: There is no element that has the id `oneImage` when `document.getElementById("oneImage")` was executed.

Answer (score 1):

There is something on your post I can't understand. So I make a demo to achieve your following.It works well.

[This is JSFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/rnahga7y/)

This is my javascript included by the function `window.onload = function (){}`. Pay more attention `intNumber`.

```
var theImage = document.getElementById("oneImage");
changeAds();
var intNumber = 0;
function changeAds() {

  var arrayOfImages = [
    "http://img2.zol.com.cn/product/91/15/ces2fuhxjcejw.jpg", "http://img2.zol.com.cn/product/91/19/ce6ND3v9hwMpY.jpg",
    "http://img2.zol.com.cn/product/91/18/ce2Ta7Kez9P.jpg"];
  // starting function ads 

  theImage.src =  arrayOfImages[intNumber];
  intNumber++;
  if (intNumber == arrayOfImages.length) {
    intNumber = 0;
  }

}
setInterval(changeAds, 1000);
```

Comment: There is not need to call changeAds() on its own.

Answer (score 0):

- You have a global var you are overwriting in the function - remove `intNumber` from the function.
- You have another global var, you are setting before the image exists.
- Also you are calling the setInterval wrong - you need to remove the ()

---

```
var theImage, 
    intNumber = 0,
    arrayOfImages = ["images/cvb1,gif","images/cvb2,gif","images/cvb3,gif"];
window.onload=function() {
  theImage = document.getElementById("oneImage"); 
  setInterval(changeAds,2000);
}    

// starting function ads 
function changeAds(){
   theImage.setAttribute("src",arrayOfImages[intNumber]);
   intNumber ++;
   if (intNumber==arrayOfImages.length){
       intNumber=0;
   }
}
```

Comment: But `theImage` would still be undefined though.

Comment: Also, if the script is defined in the header, `getElementById("oneImage")` will return null as dom element is not yet created. You should move that in `changeAds()`

Comment: Not any more. I moved it into the window.onload